# How to solve the error: Warning call_user_func_array() C...\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Explanation: I have recently installed version 4.7.10.

My program is failing after the upgrade. How can I solve the error found below:

```
    **( ! ) Warning: call_user_func_a rray() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myplguin_admin_sub_page' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp64\www\sumit\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0050  308232  {main}( )   ...\admin.php:0
    2   0.8550  33806248    do_action( )    ...\admin.php:222
    3   0.8550  33806968    WP_Hook->do_action( )   ...\plugin.php:453
    4   0.8550  33807048    WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   ...\class-wp-hook.php:323
    5   0.8550  33807848    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp64\www\sumit\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:298} ( )    ...\class-wp-hook.php:298**
```

Comment: Need more code to to actually help. But you probably called your function `myplguin_admin_sub_page()` without a "required" parameter. Please give us more code.

Comment: Major refactoring due to poor grammar and formatting.

Comment: here is the full code [link] (http://project.ostpl.com/demo/text) @Willi